# Change class that extends JFrame to class that extends JPanel

Tags: java, jframe, jtable, jpanel, ucanaccess

I'm a Java-Newbie an I'm trying to build my first app. I read lots of tutorials and demos and searched for concrete answers to my question but haven't found something that helps.
For testing I wrote this class, that connects an access database with a JTable. Now I want to add this Class in a main app but therefore i have to change my exisiting class to JPanel. I tested some changes, but I don't get an output JTable inside my app anymore. Can anybody explain the way I have to change my class? Thanks a lot!

```
    package de.test.gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

class Projekt {
    private int Platz;
    private String ProjektName;
    private String StimmZahl;

    public Projekt(int platz, String projektName, String stimmZahl) {
        this.Platz = platz;
        this.ProjektName = projektName;
        this.StimmZahl = stimmZahl;
    }

    public int getPlatz(){
        return this.Platz;
    }

    public String getProjektName() {
        return this.ProjektName;
    }

    public String getStimmZahl(){
        return this.StimmZahl;
    }

}
public class TabelleProjekt extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TabelleProjekt() {
        super();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setSize(500,300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    static Connection getConnection() {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
          con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Projekt/testdb.accdb");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Logger.getLogger(TabelleProjekt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return con;
    }

    static ArrayList<Projekt> getProjekt() {
        ArrayList<Projekt> projekt = new ArrayList<Projekt>();

        Connection con = getConnection();
        Statement st;
        ResultSet rs;
        Projekt p;

        try {
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TESTTABLE");

            while(rs.next()){
                p = new Projekt(
                        rs.getInt("KBOE"),
                        rs.getString("NAME"),
                        rs.getString("VORNAME")
                );
                projekt.add(p);

            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Logger.getLogger(TabelleProjekt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return projekt;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JTable table = new JTable();

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        Object[] columnsName = new Object [3];
        columnsName[0] = "Platz";
        columnsName[1] = "Projektname";
        columnsName[2] = "Stimmzahl";

        model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnsName);

        Object[] rowData = new Object[3];

        for (int i = 0; i < getProjekt().size(); i++) {
            rowData[0] = getProjekt().get(i).getPlatz();
            rowData[1] = getProjekt().get(i).getProjektName();
            rowData[2] = getProjekt().get(i).getStimmZahl();

            model.addRow(rowData);

        }

        table.setModel(model);
        System.out.println(getProjekt().size());
        TabelleProjekt window = new TabelleProjekt();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
        panel.add(pane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        window.setContentPane(panel);
        window.setVisible(true);


    } 


}
```

If I change it to

```
public class TabelleProjekt extends JPanel {
```

I get problems here:

```
public TabelleProjekt() {
    super();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

window.setContentPane(panel);
```

Now I tried to use camickrs advice and use my logic in a SimpleTableDemo. Somehow it still doesn't work.

```
package de.test.gui;

/*
 * SimpleTableDemo.java requires no other files.
 */

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class SimpleTableDemo extends JPanel {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private boolean DEBUG = false;

    static Connection getConnection() {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Projekt/testdb.accdb");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Logger.getLogger(TabelleProjekt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return con;
    }

    class Projekt {
        private int Platz;
        private String ProjektName;
        private String StimmZahl;

        public Projekt(int platz, String projektName, String stimmZahl) {
            this.Platz = platz;
            this.ProjektName = projektName;
            this.StimmZahl = stimmZahl;
        }

        public int getPlatz() {
            return this.Platz;
        }

        public String getProjektName() {
            return this.ProjektName;
        }

        public String getStimmZahl() {
            return this.StimmZahl;
        }

        ArrayList<Projekt> getProjekt() {
            ArrayList<Projekt> projekt = new ArrayList<Projekt>();

            Connection con = getConnection();
            Statement st;
            ResultSet rs;
            Projekt p;

            try {
                st = con.createStatement();
                rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM JK_850_All_for_Vest_Future_T");

                while (rs.next()) {
                    p = new Projekt(rs.getInt("KBOE"), rs.getString("NAME"), rs.getString("VORNAME"));
                    projekt.add(p);

                }

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Logger.getLogger(TabelleProjekt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            return projekt;

        }

        public void SimpleTableDemo() {
            /*
             * super(new GridLayout(1,0));
             */

            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
            Object[] columnsName = new Object[3];
            columnsName[0] = "Platz";
            columnsName[1] = "Projektname";
            columnsName[2] = "Stimmzahl";

            model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnsName);

            Object[] rowData = new Object[3];

            for (int i = 0; i < getProjekt().size(); i++) {
                rowData[0] = getProjekt().get(i).getPlatz();
                rowData[1] = getProjekt().get(i).getProjektName();
                rowData[2] = getProjekt().get(i).getStimmZahl();

                model.addRow(rowData);

                final JTable table = new JTable(model);
                table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 370));
                table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

                if (DEBUG) {
                    table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                            printDebugData(table);
                        }
                    });
                }

                // Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
                JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

                // Add the scroll pane to this panel.
                add(scrollPane);
            }

        }

    }

    private void printDebugData(JTable table) {
        int numRows = table.getRowCount();
        int numCols = table.getColumnCount();
        javax.swing.table.TableModel model = table.getModel();

        System.out.println("Value of data: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
            System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
            for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
                System.out.print("  " + model.getValueAt(i, j));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------");

    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it. For thread safety, this method should be
     * invoked from the event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        // Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleTableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Create and set up the content pane.
        SimpleTableDemo newContentPane = new SimpleTableDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); // content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 370));

        // Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        // creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I just get an empty window

Comment: "Now I want to add this Class in a main app but therefore I have to change my existing class to JPanel." why?.Anyway, to make your existing class be treated like a JPanel simply extend JPanel.

Comment: You cann't just add a window to a container.  Instead, start by changing `public class TabelleProjekt extends JFrame {` to `public class TabelleProjekt extends JPanel {`. Now `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout` by default, so you want to update the layout manager in the classes constructor

Comment: I've already tried it. The Problem is that I get three problems after that:  setLocationRelativeTo(null); , setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); and window.setContentPane(panel); getting Errors. And here I'm not sure what to do after that. Everything I tried to change made the code doesn't work anymore. Even if there aren't any errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code relating to the frame can't be part of the class that extend the JPanel. That code should be part of the main() method of your class that creates the GUI.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

The `SimpleTableDemo` shows one way to structure your code so that the important logic is part of the class extending the JPanel.

Edit:

> I have two objects that return columnnames and data from the database.... says my objects are undefined?!

Well the structure of your code is wrong if you are getting a compile error.

A simple way is to create a method to return the TableModel:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class SSCCE extends JPanel
{
    SSCCE()
    {
        JTable table = new JTable( getTableModel() );
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );

        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private TableModel getTableModel()
    {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(5, 3);

        return model;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new SSCCE());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }
}
```

I gave a simple implementation of the `getTableModel()` method.

Now you need to modify that method to get the data from your data base. So you need to:

1. build the SQL
2. get the ResultSet
3. get the column names from the ResultSet
4. get the rows of data from the ResultSet
5. create the DefaultTableModel using the column names and data
6. return the DefaultTableModel

Note there is no need for the `Projekt` class if you are just going to store each field separately in the TableModel. So get this simple approach working first.

Once you get the above suggestion working you may want to consider store the `Projekt` object in the TableModel. In this case you will need to create a custom TableModel. Checkout  [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for an example of creating a custom TableModel for a specific object.

The purpose of the TableModel is to store the data. There should be no need for the ArrayList. That is you don't want to store data in two places. So the data from the ResultSet should be loaded directly to the TableModel.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to edit my code and put it into a SimpleTableDemo class. I posted the code in my question. Still no success. Where is my mistake?

Comment: `Still no success.` - what does that mean? Again walk before your run. Start with the code from the tutorial. Remove the code not related to your requirement. Then modify the code so that you display only the table in a scrollpane with the column names. That part is easy because all the data is hard coded. Once that works then you start worrying about adding data from the database. So solve one problem at a time. When it stops working then you know the area that is causing the problem. For example, why are you trying to create a new table/scrollpane for every row in the ResultSet?

Comment: My problem starts here: final JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames); - I have two objects that return columnnames and data from the database. But when I insert both variables eclipse says my objects are  undefined?!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!